# Python Cryptography Fernet AES Encryption newlines, indents, carriage returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I have to encrypt a string with a key and store the encrypted object as a string, it has to be strong so I decided to use a module providing aes encryption "Cryptography" https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/

As you can see, I made a series of functions to make easy use of Fernet encryption, however for some reason it cannot handle backslashes, newlines, indents and carriage returns, the resulting decryption being different than the original string, the test string here is `"t\n\t"`

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
import base64

def encrypt_string(string_, password, f = None):
    if f is None:
        f = get_fernet_(password)
    try:
        return str(f.encrypt(string_.encode()))[2:- 1]
    except:
        return None

def decrypt_string(string_, password, f = None):
    if f is None:
        f = get_fernet_(password)
    try:
        return str(f.decrypt(string_.encode()))[2:- 1]
    except:
        return None

def get_fernet_(password):
    if password and isinstance(password,str):
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm = hashes.SHA256(),
                         length = 32,
                         salt = password.encode(),
                         iterations = 100000,
                         backend = default_backend())
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password.encode()))
        f = Fernet(key)
        return f

def test_encryption(s = "text", password = "key"):
    my_f = get_fernet_(password)
    s2 = encrypt_string(s, password)
    s3 = decrypt_string(s2, password)
    s4 = encrypt_string(s, password, my_f)
    s5 = decrypt_string(s4, password, my_f)
    if s == s3 and s == s5:
        return True
    return False

print (test_encryption("text"))
True

print (test_encryption("t\n\t"))
False
```

If anyone could provide a solution for this particular code or a different encryption algorithm that can do what I need

Comment: Your code fails for any input string because you're slicing the ciphertext; `Fernet.decrypt()` expects the full output of `Fernet.encrypt()`. Also, this is a very bad way to handle exceptions.

Comment: @t.m.adam not true, if you test it with another string which does not contain any backslashes you will see. Regarding the exceptions, these functions are just for my own use, I don't need debugging, I just need to know if it failed or not, None will do that

Comment: Well, I think your code needs debugging, it wouldn't be here if it didn't. Regardless, catching all exceptions silently is bad practice. Your code produces False for both strings on my machine (tested with Python 2.7, cryptography v1.7.2). Why are you slicing your data anyway?

Comment: @citizen2077 using a *much* simpler implementation it does not exhibit this behavior (just using a random generated fernet key) `s = 'hi\tthere'; enc=f.encrypt(s.encode()); s == f.decrypt(enc).decode()` yields `True`. I'd seriously take a look at your `decrypt_string` method and the slice you implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to convert a `bytes` object to a `string` using the `str` literal, rather than the `bytes.decode()` method:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Im just using a random key for simplicity
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

mystr = 'hi\tthere'

enc = f.encrypt(mystr.encode()) # str.encode() creates a bytes object
dec = f.decrypt(enc)

str(dec)
# "b'hi\\tthere'"
# This is NOT the same, use decode

mystr==str(dec[2:-1]) # returns False
mystr==dec.decode() # returns True

dec.decode()
# 'hi\tthere'
```